# python unittest run server & client and pass raw_input

Tags: python, client-server, functional-testing

I've got an easy [python socket game](https://github.com/tkoomzaaskz/noughts-and-crosses) which has server and client scripts. I've provided unit tests using `unittest` module (to test abstract game logic) and now I want to provide functional tests (to test a real socket game runtime).

From python code, I'd like to run the server first and then the client. These use `raw_input` (py2.7) functions, so I need to pass some information to those scripts (each game move is read from the console using `raw_input`).

How can I do this in python/unittest? I mean - how can I run external scripts and pass console input to them - from python code?

Comment: Move `raw_input` out of the core functions. It should only be present in the code that interacts with the user.

Comment: @Blender it's not in the core functions. The core is game.py and it's pure logic. Server and Client (two players) use raw_input. My question is - how can I pass some input from functional-tests level?

Comment: You could probably hack something together, but that's not a good approach. `Game.move` uses `raw_input`.

Comment: Well, no, because this file (https://github.com/tkoomzaaskz/noughts-and-crosses/blob/master/nac/game.py) holds the logic and it's unit tested. I want to test client-server communication. They are both console apps using raw_input. I already solved this problem (using nosetests, subprocesses and pipes for supplying raw_input) here: https://github.com/tkoomzaaskz/noughts-and-crosses/blob/master/test/test_functional.py.

Comment: Like I said, that's a hack. If your application was structured properly, you wouldn't need to call your script from within your unit test.

Comment: disagree, but nevermind ;)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to mock raw_input. Using [mock library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) or just mocking it yourself - can be even simpler, for example:

```
def ri_mock(fle_name='nac_input.txt'):
    with open(fle_name) as fp:
        for ln in fp:
            yield ln

gen = ri_mock()
raw_input = gen.next
```

However, since you are going to use it in unit test, I would rather use string instead of reading data from external file.

Comment: it turned out that the solution to what I wanted was to run the server/client as threads inside one nosetests test and set file pipes to server/client threads.

Comment: Being honest I did not know that you are planning to test both sides at the same time, especially that in your question you have written "I'd like to run the server first and then the client.". Anyway, I am glad that you have solved your problem.

Comment: sorry for being imprecise - I meant that the server opens the socket and the client binds to this socket ;)